# Vignette collab template language name and reference

Tags: templates, collaboration, vignette

What is the name of the programming language enclosed by ISPECT tags used in Vignette Collaboration ? Is there any refence for that beast ? thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is [jython](http://www.jython.org/)